# net core console app C# HttpClient hangs when request takes long

Tags: c#, .net-core, console-application, httpclient

Console App Net Core 3.0

I'm sending batch requests to Dynamic CRM Api, basically I read one folder looking for text files that are generated by another process (Nodejs) those files have the request content, then I iterate throught those files, take the text content as string and send it. <strike>The problem is when the content of any of those files is bigger (500kb+)</strike> The problem is when the requests takes longer (5 minutes or longer) then the `HttpClient.SendAsync` starts but NEVER completes, the system hangs there, I know the sending was successful cause I check in the api and the changes are applied but the automated process stops there and I have to kill the app. If the content is not that big then everything runs smoothly.

The most frustrating thing is there's no any error or feedback that leads me to any solution or workaround.

Important details:

I think this shouldn't be a deadlock since every single async call in the chain is awaited, the sendasync is also set to ConfigureAwait(false). No .Result, no Wait() or any other blocking operation is called.

I'm not exhausting netword sockets by creating one HttpClient instance per request, I'm using `IHttpClientFactory` to dispatch the httpClient instance as Singleton. And the issue happens at the first long content request it comes across.

**Update**
I realized the problem has nothing to do with the payload size but with the time the request takes to complete, I noticed files of 200kb or less hangs because the server takes more than 8 minutes to complete.

The code:

```
        HttpRequestMessage GetRequest(string batchId, string requestBody)
        {
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post,"$batch");
            request.Headers.Add("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
            request.Headers.Add("OData-Version", "4.0");
            request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            request.Content = GetContent(batchId, requestBody);

            return request;
        }

         StringContent GetContent(string batchId, string requestBody)
        {
            var content = new StringContent(requestBody);
            content.Headers.Remove("Content-Type");
            content.Headers.Add("Content-Type", $"multipart/mixed;boundary=batch_{batchId}");

            return content;
        }
        string GetRequestBody(string file)
        {
            var requestBody = "";
            using (var sr = new StreamReader(file))
            {
                requestBody = sr.ReadToEnd();
            }

            return requestBody;
        }

        private async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendRequest(string batchId, string file)
        {    
            // this call is awaited since the access token may expire then is necessary to request a new one
            var httpClient = await _httpClientBuilder.BuildHttpClient().ConfigureAwait(false);

             var requestBody = GetRequestBody(file); // Here I read the text from the file

            using(var request = GetRequest(batchId, requestBody)){
              using(var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead).ConfigureAwait(false)){ // after this call nothing is executed
                  if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                  {
                      CustomConsole.Success("({0})Successfully Sent batch: {1}", response.StatusCode, batchId);
                      File.Delete(file);
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      CustomConsole.Error("({0}) Error sending batch: {1}", response.StatusCode, batchId);
                      var responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                      CustomConsole.Info("Response Body:");
                      CustomConsole.Info("{0}",responseBody);
                  }
       

                  return response;   
                }
            }
           
        }
```

Comment: Hi, were you able to find a solution for your issue?